# After installing Tor, I get this: "Another program is currently using this file"

Tags: windows, startup

Just like this:

https://gyazo.com/b3f0e90e84fad2c3335b5873733e6d24

I have opened up Task Manager, and I cannot find any firefox or Tor processes. I a on Windows 8.1.

I have never tried using Tor before, so I don't really know what I'm doing.

edit: when I restarted I get this:

https://gyazo.com/952af57f6ed423a0ed20a4fb7eb3448b

Comment: When in doubt, restart. This should fix the problem.

Comment: Even after restart it doesn't work, then I get this: https://gyazo.com/952af57f6ed423a0ed20a4fb7eb3448b

Comment: We'll need to know which file it's complaining about. It appears the error box has truncated the filepath, and I doubt you can enlarge the box to show the full path. Can you try starting the browser from the command line (i.e. running the .exe from `cmd`) and collecting any logs that are output?

Comment: I get the same windows 8 error, and the command line states: "Access is denied.", that is all.

Comment: Just to check: what command did you try to run from the command line? (And from the GUI, what were you clicking on?)

Comment: first I cd'd to the folder, then I just ran "firefox.exe".

https://gyazo.com/1322c28cfaee9871d8f4bb3f20548146

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the `Start Tor Browser.exe` executable in the main `Tor Browser` directory, rather than the `firefox.exe` you're trying to run.

There's a very detailed guide on EFF's [Surveillance Self-Defense](https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/how-use-tor-windows) page on how to run the Tor Browser for the first time on Windows.